# yield with walrus operator := causes syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9, contextmanager, walrus-operator

```
import contextlib
from win32com.client import Dispatch  

@contextlib.contextmanager
def excel_ctx() -> Generator[Dispatch, None, None] :
    try:
        yield excel := Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    finally:
        excel.quit()
```

Is meant to create a new Excel App and call its quit method every time. I thought it could be written more concisely with the walrus operator, but I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis around the walrus operator like this:

```py
yield (excel := Dispatch("Excel.Application"))
```